# fitting size to content on smaller screen size

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application.When I start it on a desktop PC,it looks great.But when I start the app on a laptop with a smaller screen size,one of my windows can't fit.
It looks something like this
[image]

When I put the set size to content to WidhtAndHeight,I get
[image]

This fits my window,but my two down buttons are right on the edge of a window.I want to have some extra space between the buttons and the edge of a window.
I tried setting

Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"

Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">

and

Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"

Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"

but it gives me the same result as on picture number two.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Zavod.Objekat.ObjekatIzmena"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Zavod.Objekat"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="sadas" Height="796" Width="1114" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" FontFamily="Verdana" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Background="#FFA38566" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,4,0">
  <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="626" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1104" Background="#FFA38566">
            <TabItem Header="Општи подаци">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="459"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Кључ:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="345,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label_Copy" Content="Повезивање:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="345,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label_Copy1" Content="Линк за слику 1:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="345,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label_Copy2" Content="Линк за слику 2:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="345,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label_Copy3" Content="Линк за слику 3:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="345,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label_Copy4" Content="Линк за слику 4:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="345,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxKljuc" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,27,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxPovezivanje" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,58,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLinkZaSliku1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,89,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Background="#FFECE7B7"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLinkZaSliku2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,120,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Background="#FFECE7B7"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLinkZaSliku3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,151,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Background="#FFECE7B7"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLinkZaSliku4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,181,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Background="#FFECE7B7"/>


                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
 </TabControl>
 <Button x:Name="buttonSnimiObjekat" Content="Измени" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231,660,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonSnimiObjekat_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonOdustani" Content="Откажи" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="816,660,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonOdustani_Click" />


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Show your full xaml code.

Comment: I edited the comment

Comment: it is a bad practice to use hard-coded sizes in xaml.
If you remove it, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Yo have also used margin to create a distance between your objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See an example how your layout should be created:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
        <TabItem Header="Општи подаци">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label x:Name="label"
                       Content="Кључ:" />
                <Label x:Name="label_Copy"
                       Content="Повезивање:"
                       Grid.Row="2" />
                <Label x:Name="label_Copy1"
                       Content="Линк за слику 1:"
                       Grid.Row="4" />

                <TextBox x:Name="textBoxKljuc"
                         Grid.Column="2"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         IsEnabled="False" />
                <TextBox x:Name="textBoxPovezivanje"
                         Grid.Column="2"
                         Grid.Row="2"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         IsEnabled="False" />
                <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLinkZaSliku1"
                         Grid.Column="2"
                         Grid.Row="4"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Background="#FFECE7B7" />

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Grid.Row="2">
        <Button x:Name="buttonSnimiObjekat"
                Content="Измени" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonOdustani"
                Content="Откажи" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Your problem are constant margins and sizes. That happens when you use Expression Blend and doesn't write your XAML manually.

Comment: I see your point.But will this create space between my two buttons and the edge of a window that is right under them? I need that

Comment: You need to control the size of your window only through the Width and Height properties of the Window control. If you have a lot of free space - you should make your window smaller.